# node async/await -- do I need try/catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm just playing around with async/await in node and it seems that if you're awaiting a promise and it gets rejected that it throws.  I'm wondering if there is a cleaner pattern than going back to try/catch blocks that I'm not aware of?

```
async function foo() {
  const val = await Promise.reject();
}
```

Comment: It seems this is the way it is right now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you consider "cleaner"?

Comment: @jib - try/catch is not clean control structure.  A rejected promise doesn't always mean an error, and an error at one level doesn't always constitute an error at a higher level (for instance `fs.access` throws if you can't access a file, but this is the appropriate way to check _if_ you have access).  `try/catch` is meant for _unexpected_ errors, not expected ones.

Answer (score 1):

`try`/`catch()` *is* the cleaner pattern, aligning synchronous and asynchronous error handling:

(Works in Chrome and Firefox Developer Edition at the moment)

```js
function a(heads) {
  if (heads) throw new Error("Synchronous error");
}

async function b() {
  await Promise.resolve();
  throw new Error("Asynchronous error");
}

async function main(heads) {
  try {
    a(heads);
    await b();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
main(false); // Synchronous error
main(true);  // Asynchronous error
```